# Class type injection in Spring xml vs java config

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-java-config, spring-ioc

```
Class X{
   Class<B> object;
   public setObject( Class<B> a ){....}
}

Interface B{}
Interface C extends B {}
```

I instantiate X like this,

```
X x = new X();
x.setObject( C.class );
```

When i build the code it complains required `Class<B>` found `Class<C>`. Since C extends B, can i not use C.class? If so can some one explain why?

I i do the same thing using Spring`s XML based bean creating it works just fine. The bean definition would be

```
<bean id="dummy" class="X">
<property name"object" value="C">
</bean>
```

This works just fine. Im not getting why instantiating in java would fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not valid Java code

It works because there is type erasure done for parameters <>

the java bytecode looks exactly the same as the one for

```
class X{
   Class object;
   public void setObject( Class a ){....}
}

interface B{}
interface C extends B {}
```

It looses the type checks information, it is only used at compile time.

You can use this to make it work in the code:

```
class X{
   Class<? extends B> object;
   public void setObject( Class<? extends B> a ){....}
}

interface B{}
interface C extends B {}
```

Answer (score 1):

[The same way a `List<Dog>` is not assignable to `List<Animal>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p), `Class<C>` is not assignable to `Class<B>`, even if `C` is a subtype of `B`.

Using XML configuration, you are ignoring all type safety rules. It's as if every parametrized type usage was erased, as if you were using raw types. A `Class<C>` becomes a `Class` and a `Class<B>` becomes a `Class`. A `Class` is assignable to a `Class`.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal that `setObject(Class<B>)` won't take a `Class<C>` parameter,
for the same reason that `someMethod(List<Object>)` won't take a `List<Integer>` parameter:
`List<Integer>` is not a subclass of `List<Object>`, even though `Integer` is a subclass of `Object`.

To make it work, you can change your method signature to this:

```
public setObject(Class<? extends B> a) {....}
```